# In which household equipment can i find an alternator or a generator or a dynamo (about 17V)?

Tags: everyday-life, electronics, electrical-engineering

equipment required: dynamo or an alternator or generator (all should be small about 17V).

As due to COVID19 i am unable to buy any of the mentioned equipment as the online shopping service providers are unable to deliver at my place. So i thought instead of wasting my time i could go some repairing shops to search for them, but if i could know in which household equipment i could find one of them then i will make my work a lot easier .Please help me out.

Comment: If you can find a motor with fixed magnets and brushes (not electromagnets and not an induction motor) and which runs at somewhere near 18V it might work. Maybe.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about physics within the scope defined in the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very nice DC motors can be easily removed for salvage from cordless electric drills or cordless weed trimmers. These are plentiful and cheap in second-hand stores.